# Scheduled task Windows shutdown - Will this run if Windows Update is busy?

Tags: windows, windows-update, shutdown, scheduled-tasks

The company would like all employee PCs to be automatically shut down via a Scheduled Task which automatically runs each evening. I have set up a task to run:

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s
```

at e.g. 6 pm in the evening every day.

(These are just thin client PCs used by staff.)

**My question is:**  Would the task still run if *Windows Update* were smack in the middle of installing important system updates? Or would Windows Update prevent the task from running?

e.g. Task scheduled for 6 p.m. But at 6 p.m. Windows Update is installing with message "Do not turn off your computer". Will the scheduled task be blocked? Or will it run and possibly bork the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schedule task will run if the system is not restarting at that point.

If updates are not yet at the point of restarting, the system will shut down.

If updates are pending restart, the shut down will install updates and restart.

At that point, the scheduled time has passed and the computer will keep running.

This should not be an issue once in a while.

Comment: Thanks John! For clarification: If the Windows Update installation is at say 50% complete at the scheduled time of the task, the shutdown will be triggered and potentially cause corruption. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: If the update is in process, shut down will complete the process and not cause any corruption.